# How to read website content from url in flutter

Tags: html, web, flutter, dart

I need an application that reads the content of a site, given the url it navigates the DOM and extracts the content of the components.

Comment: I don't know anything about Flutter or Dart really but I do think some more details would be useful to someone trying to answer. Have you tried anything to do this so far? Does any part of this functionality work as of now for your app?

Comment: I did something similar using geckodriver on the desktop

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is called "web crawler", And mostly web crawlers are working on servers not on mobile applications. mobile applications are connected to these web crawler servers through API's. so first things first you have to make a web server with some language like Python or PHP which they have open source libraries for web crawling then make an API for that server then use that API for your mobile applications.